# PHP/MySQL Rank by multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, web, rank

I'm developing a game that scores players in 2 different ways, A, B.
In this game I have a ranking page that shows what position you are in ranking A, B and A+B as well as a list of players ordered by A+B.

What would be the most efficient way to retrieve your rank in these different scoring situations as well as the nearby users for rank A+B (to display on the list)?

I assume I would have to do a pass over every user at least once. Should I attempt this with multiple left joins and subselects and count users with score A/B/A+B greater than yours, or just query for the whole user+score list and calculate the ranks with a PHP function?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
UID |  A  |  B
----------------
 1  | 100 | 50
 2  | 150 | 20
 3  | 10  | 100
```

Assuming the user viewing the ranking is UID=2 we should see:

**SCORE LIST (A+B):**
*2 - 170*
1 - 150
3 - 110

You are **#1** in Score A.
You are **#3** in Score B.
You are **#1** in Score A+B.

Comment: Can you add example data and expected output?

Comment: Edited for example data and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table my_table
(UID int not null auto_increment primary key
 ,A  int not null
 ,B  int not null
 );

 insert into my_table values
 (1,100,50),
 (2,150,20),
 (3,10,100);

 SELECT uid
     , FIND_IN_SET(a,a_score) a_rank
     , FIND_IN_SET(b,b_score) b_rank
     , FIND_IN_SET(a+b,ab_score)ab_rank

  FROM my_table
     , ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a ORDER BY a DESC) a_score
              , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b ORDER BY b DESC) b_score
              , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a+b ORDER BY a+b DESC) ab_score
           FROM my_table
       ) n
  [WHERE uid=2];

+-----+--------+--------+---------+
| uid | a_rank | b_rank | ab_rank |
+-----+--------+--------+---------+
|   1 |      2 |      2 |       2 |
|   2 |      1 |      3 |       1 |
|   3 |      3 |      1 |       3 |
+-----+--------+--------+---------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97da6/13

Comment: Thanks. I probably should be asking this in another question, but what would be the best way to load the score list (as per part 1 of my example output)?

Considering the table might have ~10000 rows, is it too heavy to pull all the records at once or is there any way to store the result in another table and lazy load as necessary? This would need the computed rank table to be deleted/updated anytime a change in score happens. I'm just not sure how to tell "if you want to pull the scores/rank, check if they have been calculated already, otherwise, calculate them again".

Comment: Suck it and see, but I'd probably write the whole thing to an external json file and call it via a bit of JavaScript. I can't really elaborate on that because it's not really my forte.